# How to make the CSS :focus work on my project?

Tags: css, focus, pseudo-class

Can anyone help me? I tried to add a border-color using :focus on the form input when the user clicks on the text field. But it doesn't work. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

```css
form.customNewsletter-form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 16px;
}

form.customNewsletter-form input[type="text"] {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  width: 70%;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
}

form.customNewsletter-form input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #cd0d0d;
}

form.customNewsletter-form input::placeholder {
  color: #8d8d8d;
}

form.customNewsletter-form input[type="submit"] {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #cd0d0d;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 48px !important;
  width: 30%;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

form.customNewsletter-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #8e0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
  transform: scale(0.99) 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<form class="customNewsletter-form" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
  <!-- Email field (required) -->
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
  <!-- List token -->
  <!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
  <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="sample">
  <!-- Thank you page (optional) -->
  <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://www.website.com/thankyou">
  <!-- Add subscriber to the follow-up sequence with a specified day (optional) -->
  <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0">
  <!-- Subscriber button -->
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Please see [here](https://codepen.io/denzdoneza/pen/ExpQbrj) for the demo.

I'm expecting the border-color of the input field to change to red when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Where is the problem? when the input is focused the border color change.....

Comment: it works as expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add outline:none;

```
form.customNewsletter-form input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #cd0d0d;
}
```